# Spring Cloud Config incorrect property override

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have property

```
password: '{cipher}xxxx'
```

in my application.yml properties file. When Spring Cloud Config Server overrides value of this property with decrypted value I get something like

```
password: "data-raw=decryptedpassword"
```

I saw that using `/{application}/{profile}` endpoint. Is there any way to remove this prefix `"data-raw="` from decrypted value?

Comment: What version of spring cloud are you using? How are you configuring config server. That URL is for use by config client. Is the value wrong using config client? There are other URLs for non-java workloads.

Comment: @spencergibb, problem solved. I thought It was the way how decoder returns values, but somehow the value, that was encypted was "data-raw=decryptedpassword" itself, so I couldn't figure it out whether it's my or decoder's fault. Thanks.